# How to add Search Dialog to an Android app

Tags: java, android, search-dialog

Here is my issue. I have a requirement to add a **search dialog** to an Android app. I have found the way to add a search view component, but not the search dialog. I know from the Android Developers docs that I am supposed to use `onSearchRequested()` to make it appear, but I don't quite understand what that means. Is the search dialog supposed to be tied to my own UI component that will invoke this method or am I missing something? I haven't managed to read all the docs on searching, but I was hoping someone may point me where I missed something important.

I am not well versed in Android development, only a few small projects. I am more of a Flutter dev when creating a mobile app, but I don't have the option this time around.

Below is the screenshot of what the Android Developers docs show as search dialog and the comparison to search view.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#SearchDialog), the steps for invoking a `Search Dialog` are:

1. create an Xml file (which you already did for `search widget`)
2. Declaring a searchable activity: create an actiivty and notify the `Manifest` that it gets the search results (you did that too)

**3.** At the `Manifest`, decalre some other activity (MainActivity for examlpe) to be able to invoke the search dialog. Add this line inside `<activity>` tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
```

(`android:value` is the name of the Activity that gets the searcg results, which you defined at step 2)

**4.** At that Activity, create a search button etc and invoke the `Serach Dialog` like this:

```
onSearchRequested();
```

Very simple actually :)

The search words stored in `intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)` as a String, you get it at `onCreate()` of `SearchableActivity` class. From this point you should handle the search query and results logic...

Comment: let me know if yo need more explanations about the first steps. I assumed you did them already

Comment: Ok once I get back to this and try it out I will tell you. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Here is the thing. It seems that I missed the search dialogue in the docs and scrolled my way all the way down to the search view solution, going to try it tonight.

Comment: Done, it works as described. +1 for the docs link.